# Ошибка Epic Games Web API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

Я пытаюсь отправить POST запрос на получение токена Epic Account Services. Делаю всё как  в их [документации](https://dev.epicgames.com/docs/web-api-ref/authentication#requesting-an-access-token), но, почему-то, появляется ошибка:

```
Unsupported grant type: null
```

API просто не видит значение gran_type.
Не знаю, в чём проблема буду рад любой помощи.
Ниже предоставляю URL, который получается на выходе и код на Python.

URL:

```
https://api.epicgames.dev/epic/oauth/v1/token?grant_type=password&deployment_id=foo&scope=basic_profile+friends_list+presence&username=example0%40gmail.com&password=pass
```

Python:

```python
import requests

url = 'https://api.epicgames.dev/epic/oauth/v1/token'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic Zm9vOmJhcg=='
}

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'deployment_id': 'foo',
    'scope': 'basic_profile friends_list presence',
    'username': 'example@gmail.com',
    'password': 'pass'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

print(r.url)

print('\n'+r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первый взгляд проблема в передаче параметров **не в теле запроса**, а в **параметрах** пути.
Правильно будет передавать в **data**.

[Дока requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```